# Valgrind unitialized bytes error due to type casting bit field to integer

Tags: c++, c++11, valgrind

```
struct A {
    A() : a(0), b_1(0), b_2(0), c(0) {}
    int a=0;
    int b_1: 9;
    int b_2: 23;
    int c=0;
};

void func1(int i, int j, int k) {   //<<<< valgrind error at this line.
}

void func2() {
    int aa = 11;
    int cc = 12;
    A a;
    a.b_2 = -1;
    func1(2, a.b_2, cc );
}
```

My program has something like this. I am getting a valgrind error like below:

```
==25167== Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==25167==    at 0x122A00E9: func1(int, int, int)
```

I am suspecting because `a.b_2` is 23 bits, and we are assigning it to 32 bit integer `j`, this is causing uninitialized bytes error?
Can this -1 loose its value when assigned to j?
is this correct?

Comment: This is not the full error message (it just tells the source of the value which is used uninitialized, not the usage itself). Put the full message here, with the whole program necessary to reproduce.

Comment: the generated code produces a 'full' _int_ from `a.b_2` setting the 'missing' bits to 0, so there is no uninitialized byte